# Cup of water and cup of water with oil on top

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, thermal-conductivity, evaporation

the teacher gave me this problem to solve. So i hope you can help me with it. Here is the problem:
John poured 150ml ob boiling water in 2 cups made out of polystyrene. Cups are open on the top so heat goes out there. Temperature of the outside air is 20°C. In 1 cup he add 5 mm thick layer of hot oil. He measured starting temperatures and then he measured temperatures again after 10 min. He measured the mass of water and water+oil before and after 10 min.

Here are the resaults:

-**cup 1 (only water)**

starting temp: 96°C

finnish temp: 64°C

starting mass: 149.4g

finnish mass: 142.42g

**-cup 2(with oil on top)**

starting temp.: 96°C

finnish temp.:91°C

starting mass: 164.72g

finnish mass: 164.70g

The surface of the both cups is 0.003 m2

**Questions:**
1.Why did the water covered with oil cooled down slower that the one with no oil? Show with calculations.
2.Why did John use oil with temperature around 100°C and not oil with room temperature? How would the resaults change if he used room temeprature oil?
3. Which other physical values, which are relevant, can you calculate from this informations?
Basiccaly i need the physics behing why does this happen.

Comment: Basically you want your homework done, but this is not a homework solving web site. It says so on the question box you filled in.

Comment: No, i need the physics behind this process... I just don't know where to start

Comment: If there was a specific part of the answering process that had you stumped, we would be more than willing to help your understanding.  We are not here to do your work while you sit back and relax.  I'm sure your teacher gave you some information on how you'd expect to solve this; or it's relevant to something you're learning.

Comment: Ok so:How do you explain why does water with oil cool down slower? Just give me a hint of where to start. What do i have to calculate?

Comment: What help are you asking for? It seems that you want us to do the homework for you.

Comment: i don't really know how to ask because i don't know the excact word in english for this. I just need an idea where to start and what to calculate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cup of water with oil on top](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307780/cup-of-water-with-oil-on-top)

EDIT: woops, should be the other way around, he posted this one first.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the significant reduction of mass (almost 7g) for the cup without oil. What do you think happened to that water? It evaporated, becoming water vapour, and was carried away by *convection*. When a liquid evaporates, the remaining liquid cools down. The hottest molecules escape, leaving cooler molecules behind. The average temperature is lower.

The water with the oil layer did not evaporate at all because the oil (which is less dense) floated on top of the water. The oil did not evaporate much (only 0.02g). How readily a liquid evaporates is called its *volatility*. Oil is less volatile than water. It contains long chain molecules which attract each other more strongly than water molecules, so they do not escape from the liquid as easily. Also it has a lower latent heat of vaporisation than water : each gramme which evaporates carries away less heat energy than water. So it does not reduce the average temperature of the remaining liquid as much.

There are other ways in which the cup of water can lose heat - *conduction* and *radiation* but these make a smaller contribution because of the polystyrene insulation.

Why use hot oil instead of cold oil? What happens when you add a cold liquid to a hot liquid? The hot liquid cools down. Then it would not be a fair experiment : we would be comparing hot water at $96^{\circ}$C with cooler water at perhaps $60^{\circ}$C. Hot water is expected to lose heat faster than cool water, and to cool down more quickly. So the oil has to be at the same temperature as the water, to avoid cooling it.

You can calculate how much heat energy was lost by the water in each case, using the formula $\Delta H=mc\Delta T$, assuming you know the specific heat capacities $c$ for water and oil. You can also calculate the heat energy taken away by the water vapour in the cup without oil, using the formula $\Delta H=mL$, assuming you know the specific latent heat of vaporisation $L$ for water. Then you can compare the figures to see how much of the difference the evaporation of water accounts for.

Although you have been given other data (ambient temperature, thickness of oil layer, area of surface of cup, time between readings) I do not think you can make any useful calculations with it.