# Cup of water with oil on top

Tags: thermodynamics, water, thermal-radiation

I was given a homeowork where i need to explain why did water cool down slower when it had a coat of oil on top of it. We had a cup with just water and a cup with same amount of water but some oil on top. I know the starting temperatures and the temperatures after 10 min in the cups, i know the volume of water and oil, i know the size of the cups, i know the mass of the mixture. But i don't know how to explain this problem with formulas. I would really like to know where to start, what to calculate. Thank you.

Comment: what was the title of the course for which this is a homework?

Comment: Heat transfer.. or thermodynamic

Comment: Please do not repost questions that are being poorly received or get closed. Edit the original to fix the problems instead.

Answer (score -3):

My first guess would be that the oil layer prevents steam from escaping. The hottest molecules in the water evaporate first, leaving behind colder water. But if the oil is there, no water can escape and so it must cool by radiating the heat away, which is less efficient.

Comment: yes but do you know what shouldi calculate to prove that? which formulas to use?

Comment: People already answered that in the other copy you posted of the same question.